# Track action within iOS app ~ create global counter

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, post, google-analytics

I would like to create a counter every time a user performs a certain action in my app, e.g. completes a level. I simply want to know this number and have a screen in my app that says, "XX,XXX levels completed"

A quick and dirty method would simply be to open a NSURL connection to one of my webpages that already has a counter on it (.png), every time they complete a level. Simple and done. But I'm wanting something a little more professional than that. And a way to share the global total to users within the app.

Would Google Analytics be capable of tracking something like this? Or am I making a mountain out of a molehill?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults. Whenever the user completes a level pull the counter value, increment the value and then save it. NSUserDefaults is global and its values will remain stored as long as the user doesn't delete your app from the device.

```
// To save the counter
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"Counter"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// To access the counter
NSNumber* counter = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Counter"];
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for the reply. I misspoke, I didn't mean "global" as in a global variable. I meant global as in, available to everyone. If 10k users complete 2 level each, I'd like to share that 20,000 levels have been completed. It's a simple integer, but how do I send/receive that value from my website (or google analytics?)